# Averaging results from 'rr_profile' for multiple iterations of statistical models

Tags: r, ggplot2, dalex

Does anyone have any experience obtained averaged results from multiple `model_profile` outputs from `DALEX`?

EDIT

To clarify, the `model_profile` function outputs partial dependence plots for one model. However, I have a list of 500 models that have been generated using different testing/training splits, and downsampled data.

Averaging results for `model_profile` with `variable_type = 'categorical'` was relatively straight forward, as each category was extracted as one value from `$agr_profiles`, which could be merged together into a large data frame.

However, I am not sure how exactly to go about averaging the entire profile 500 times to generate averaged values for the `model_profile` with `variable_type = 'continuous'`.

Reproducible example

```
library("ranger") 
library(DALEX)

trainIdx_1 <- sample(nrow(titanic_imputed), 2/3 * nrow(titanic_imputed)) 
trainData_1 <- titanic_imputed[trainIdx_1, ]

trainIdx_2 <- sample(nrow(titanic_imputed), 2/3 * nrow(titanic_imputed)) 
trainData_2 <- titanic_imputed[trainIdx_2, ]

titanic_ranger_model_1 <- ranger(survived~., data = trainData_1, num.trees = 50,
                               probability = TRUE) 
titanic_ranger_model_2 <- ranger(survived~., data = trainData_2, num.trees = 50,
                                 probability = TRUE)

exp_1 <- explain(titanic_ranger_model_1, data = trainData_1) 
exp_2 <- explain(titanic_ranger_model_2, data = trainData_2)

model_profile_1 <- model_profile(exp_1, type = "partial") 
model_profile_2 <- model_profile(exp_2, type = "partial")
```

How could I obtain the average profile from `model_profile_1` and `model_profile_2`?

Comment: It's not clear what kind of answer you are looking for here. Without a reproducible example including data and code used to create the models, it is not possible to give you a code-based answer. Please [edit] your question to make it reproducible, thanks.

Comment: Can you please advise what is it that you are trying to achieve and what exactly you want. As a first step check the DALEX package documents at following URL http://xai-tools.drwhy.ai/DALEX.html, otherwise please provide us exact details you need

Comment: Hello @QasimAlhammad, I added additional details clarifying what  I mean. I suspect the answer is related to how `$agr_profiles` are generated from `$cp_profiles`

Comment: Thank you @AllanCameron, an example has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a decent looking mean line by joining both profiles data as one dataset, and plotting a line using `ggplot`'s `stat_summary_bin`. It's not perfect, and may require some playing around with bin numbers for best results, but it works for me. Example code and output shown below. It looks better if more iterations are used

```
agrData = rbind(model_profile_1$agr_profiles, model_profile_2$agr_profiles)
plot(agrData) + stat_summary_bin(mapping = aes(y = `_yhat_`), fun = "mean", geom = "line")
```

[image: Black line is mean plot]

Answer (score 0):

thanks for sharing a reproducible example, I guess what you are trying to achieve here is to find the average prediction for each model profiler.

In your example you need to use below code

```
plot(model_profile_1$agr_profiles, model_profile_2$agr_profiles)
```

In you case you will get exactly the same results because you are using the exact same model to train the exact same data to do prediction. so no matter how many profiles you create you will get again the same results.

In order to get different results you need to build different models then only you can compare the models you built to compare models together and decide which model is working best.

if you look at the example mentioned in the DALEX package page  xai-tools.drwhy.ai/DALEX.html, you will see that first model was built with ranger and second model was built with GBM.

if you don't want to use another model than ranger, you can create multiple models with rangers but change the setting for each model, like num.trees. only then you will get a different result.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The models should not be the exact same as they are trained on different data. Your above solution plots both sets on the same sub-plots - it does not average the results

Comment: Hi @JasonConnelly sorry my bad I didn't notice that you are using to random samples of the same dataset. let me check and will get back to you if I find a solution.